# Intuition behind multiplicative unitaries

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, intuition, operator-algebras

A multiplicative unitary on a Hilbert space $H$ is a unitary $V: H \otimes H \to H\otimes H$ such that the pentagon identity
$V_{[12]} V_{[13]}V_{[23]}= V_{[23]} V_{[12]}$ holds. Here the leg-numbering notation is employed. For example,
$$V_{[12]}= V \otimes 1 \in B(H \otimes H \otimes H).$$

Is there any intuition behind this pentagon identity? I can't memorise the identity, but I need it often (in the context of quantum groups), and I think if I would have some intuition I would be able to memorise it better.

Comment: You write you "need it often, and ...": Expanding on this could be helpful for candidate answerers & will enhance your post.
Futhermore, [Is this a relevant reference?](http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1994__91_2_201_0.pdf) 
is entitled "The Yang-Baxter and pentagon equation".

Comment: @Hanno Thanks for the reference. Multiplicative unitaries often pop up in the study of compact quantum groups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $G$ is a locally compact group and $H=L^2(G)$ (for the right invariant Haar measure), then $H\otimes H$ identifies naturally
with $L^2(G\times G)$ and one may  consider the so called Kac-Takesaki
operator
$$
  V:L^2(G\times G)\to L^2(G\times G)
  $$
defined by
$$
  (V\xi )(x, y)=\xi (xy, y),\quad \forall \xi \in  L^2(G\times G) ,\quad \forall x,  y\in G.
  $$
One may easily prove that $V$ is unitary.

Notice that  $V$ codifies the multiplication operation of $G$, so it may be seen as an incarnation of the very
group structure of $G$, so much so that  $G$ itself can  be recovered from $V$.

It is easy to show  that both
$V_{[12]} V_{[13]}V_{[23]}$ and $V_{[23]} V_{[12]}$ send the square integrable function
$\xi $ on $G\times G\times G$ to the function $\eta $ given by
$$
  \eta (x, y, z)=\xi (xyz, yz, z),
  $$
so $V$ satisfies the pentagon identity.

When $H$ is an abstract Hilbert space, and $V$ is an operator on $H\otimes H$ satisfying the pentagon identity, one may therefore
suspect that something resembling a group must be in the background!

[1] *Baaj, Saad; Skandalis, Georges*, [**Multiplicative unitaries and duality for crossed products of (C^*)-algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.24033/asens.1677), Ann. Sci. Éc. Norm. Supér. (4) 26, No. 4, 425-488 (1993). [ZBL0804.46078](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0804.46078).

[2] *Sołtan, Piotr M.; Woronowicz, Stanisław L.*, [**From multiplicative unitaries to quantum groups. II**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jfa.2007.07.006), J. Funct. Anal. 252, No. 1, 42-67 (2007). [ZBL1134.46044](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1134.46044).